# Command design pattern for RPG prototype

Tags: java, design-patterns, role-playing-game

I'm writing an assistant for the tabletop RPG Pathfinder in Java. I already have a few building blocks and decided to make a small side-project to play around the Command pattern. I know that there are [controversies](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70877/are-design-patterns-really-essential-nowadays/70893#70893) about using them, so I am mostly trying to get the main ideas behind the pattern to introduce undo/redo rather than implementing it religiously.

This project is a simplified turn-based battle manager. In the model, I have actors, who can move and attack. When they have no health points left, they die. These actors are my receivers. I have two commands: Attack, and Move. Finally, I also have the command Invoker, a BattleManager which handles turns and passes orders to the Invoker, and the Main class to handle I/O with the user. I have not separated the different classes into packages for the sake of simplicity.

My main question is: have I properly understood the concept of the Command pattern?

The point that worries me is that to implement the attack command, I have an `injure` method in `Actor`, an `Attack` class, an `attack` method in BattleManager and I have to handle the attack input in `Main`. Each part seems reasonable, because each has a separate responsibility, but I fear I have made things way more complex than necessary so I'm interested in a sanity check.

I also welcome feedback on every aspect of the code before I expand on it and give it a much more interesting data model, commands and user interface.

### Actor.java

```
/**
 * Represents an actor, capable of taking actions.
 */
public class Actor {
    public final String name;
    private int xPosition;
    private int yPosition;
    /** Number of Health points of the actor. */
    private int currentHp;
    public final int damage;
    
    public Actor(String name, int initialHp, int damage, int xPos, int yPos){
        this.name = name;
        this.currentHp = initialHp;
        this.damage = damage;
        this.xPosition = xPos;
        this.yPosition = yPos;
    }
    /** Return the current number of health points of the actor. */
    public int getCurrentHp(){
        return this.currentHp;
    }
    /**
     * Subtract damages to the health points of the actor.
     * @param damage number of health points to deduct. If negative, the actor is healed.
     */
    public void injure(int damage){
        this.currentHp -= damage;
    }
    
    public boolean isAlive(){
        return (this.currentHp > 0);
    }
    /**
     * Move to a new position.
     * @param x the new x-coordinate of the actor.
     * @param y the new y-coordinate of the actor.
     */
    public void move(int x, int y){
        this.xPosition = x;
        this.yPosition = y;
    }
    
    public int getXPosition(){
        return this.xPosition;
    }
    public int getYPosition(){
        return this.yPosition;
    }
}
```

### Command.java

```
/**
 * Interface implemented by all actions that can be undone.
 */
public interface Command {
    /**
     * Perform the command.
     */
    public void execute();
    /**
     * Undo the command. This assumes that the global state is exactly as it was right after 
     * {@link #execute()} was called.
     */
    public void undo();
}
```

### Attack.java

```
/**
 * Allows an actor to attack another.
 */
public class Attack implements Command {
    private final int damage;
    private final Actor target;
    
    public Attack(Actor target, int damage){
        this.damage = damage;
        this.target = target;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void execute(){
        target.injure(damage);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void undo(){
        target.injure(-damage);
    }
}
```

### Move.java

```
/**
 * Allows an actor to move.
 */
public class Move implements Command {
    private final int[] origin;
    private final int[] endpoint;
    private final Actor actor;
    
    public Move(Actor actor, int nextX, int nextY){
        this.origin = new int[]{actor.getXPosition(), actor.getYPosition()};
        this.endpoint = new int[]{nextX, nextY};
        this.actor = actor;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void execute(){
        actor.move(endpoint[0], endpoint[1]);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void undo(){
        actor.move(origin[0], origin[1]);
    }
}
```

### Invoker.java

```
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.LinkedList;
/**
 * Invoker of the command design pattern. Handles the execution, undoing and redoing of commands.
 */
public class Invoker {
    private final Deque<Command> executedCommands = new LinkedList<>();
    private final Deque<Command> undoneCommands = new LinkedList<>();
    private final static int MAX_UNDO_STACK_SIZE = 3;
    
    Invoker(){}
    /**
     * Utility method to factor the internal workings of archiving a command.
     * @param command Command executed or undone.
     * @param receiver Queue in which the command must be archived.
     */
    private static void commandArchiver(Command command, Deque<Command> receiver){
        receiver.addFirst(command);
        if (receiver.size() > MAX_UNDO_STACK_SIZE){
            receiver.removeLast();
        }
    }
    public void execute(Command command){
        command.execute();
        commandArchiver(command, executedCommands);
        undoneCommands.clear();
    }
    public void undo(){
        Command command = executedCommands.removeFirst();
        command.undo();
        commandArchiver(command, undoneCommands);
    }
    public boolean canUndo(){
        return executedCommands.size() > 0;
    }
    public void redo(){
        Command command = undoneCommands.removeFirst();
        command.execute();
        commandArchiver(command, executedCommands);
    }
    public boolean canRedo(){
        return undoneCommands.size() > 0;
    }
}
```

### BattleManager.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Manages the course of a battle. Keeps track of actors in presence and turns, and determines when
 * the battle is won and by whom.
 */
public class BattleManager {
    private final List<Actor> actors = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Invoker invoker = new Invoker();
    private int turnIndex = 0;
    private Actor winner = null;
    
    public BattleManager(Actor... actors){
        this.actors.addAll(Arrays.asList(actors));
    }
    
    public List<Actor> getActors(){
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(actors);
    }
    /** Return the index of the actor currently playing. */
    public int getCurrentActorIndex(){
        return turnIndex;
    }
    /** Return the actor that won the battle, or null if no actor has won yet. */
    public Actor isWon(){
        return winner;
    }
    /** Move the actor currently playing to a new position. */
    public String move(int x, int y){
        Actor actor = actors.get(turnIndex);
        Actor collision = null;
        for (Actor candidate:actors){
            if (candidate.getXPosition() == x && candidate.getYPosition() == y){
                collision = candidate;
                break;
            }
        }
        String result;
        if (collision == null){
            result = actor.name + " moves from [" + actor.getXPosition() + ", " 
                    + actor.getYPosition() + "] to [" + x + ", " + y + "].";
            invoker.execute(new Move(actor, x, y));
        } else {
            result = actor.name + " tried to collide with " + collision.name 
                + ", could not move.";
            invoker.execute(new Move(actor, actor.getXPosition(), actor.getYPosition()));
        }
        turnIndex = (turnIndex+1) % actors.size();
        return result;
    }
    /** Make the actor currently playing attack another actor. */
    public String attack(Actor target){
        Actor attacker = actors.get(turnIndex);
        int damage;
        String result;
        //check if in range
        if (Math.abs(attacker.getXPosition() - target.getXPosition()) <= 1 
            && Math.abs(attacker.getYPosition() - target.getYPosition()) <= 1){
            damage = attacker.damage;
            result = attacker.name + " attacks " + target.name + " for " + damage 
                + " damage.";
        } else {
            damage = 0;
            result = attacker.name + " missed when attacking " + target.name;
        }
        invoker.execute(new Attack(target, damage));
        if (!target.isAlive()){
            winner = attacker;
        }
        turnIndex = (turnIndex+1) % actors.size();
        return result;
    }
    public void undo(){
        turnIndex = (turnIndex+actors.size()-1) % actors.size();
        invoker.undo();
    }
    public boolean canUndo(){
        return invoker.canUndo();
    }
    public void redo(){
        turnIndex = (turnIndex+1) % actors.size();
        invoker.redo();
    }
    public boolean canRedo(){
        return invoker.canRedo();
    }
}
```

### Main.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Client application. Handles I/O with the user.
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * Run the game.
     * @param args ignored
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Actor player1 = new Actor("Player1", 10, 2, 0, 0);
        Actor player2 = new Actor("Player2", 15, 1, 3, 6);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        BattleManager manager = new BattleManager(player1, player2);
        System.out.println("Battle beginning");
        while (manager.isWon() == null){
            System.out.println(getDisplayableStatus(manager));
            handleTurn(manager, scanner);
        }
        System.out.println(manager.isWon().name + " has won the battle");
    }
    /**
     * Format the current state of the battle to display it to the user.
     * @param manager BattleManager handling the battle.
     * @return a String representing the state of the players.
     */
    public static String getDisplayableStatus(BattleManager manager){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Battle status:\n");
        for (Actor actor:manager.getActors()){
            builder.append("Actor ").append(actor.name).append("\t\tPosition: ")
                .append("[").append(actor.getXPosition()).append(", ").append(actor.getYPosition())
                .append("]\t\tHealth points:").append(actor.getCurrentHp()).append("\n");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
    /**
     * Handle the course of a turn. Handle user input and perform the selected action.
     * @param manager BattleManager handling the battle.
     * @param scanner Scanner used to parse the user input.
     */
    public static void handleTurn(BattleManager manager, Scanner scanner){
        System.out.println("It is " + manager.getActors().get(manager.getCurrentActorIndex()).name 
            + "'s turn. What will he do?");
        boolean search = true;
        String result;
        while(search){
            System.out.println(possibleOptions(manager));
            String input = scanner.next();
            search = false;
            switch (input){
                case "A":
                    result = manager.attack(manager.getActors().get(
                        1-manager.getCurrentActorIndex()));
                    break;
                case "M":
                    result = manager.move(getMoveDestination(scanner, "x"), 
                            getMoveDestination(scanner, "y"));
                    break;
                case "U":
                    if (manager.canUndo()){
                        manager.undo();
                        result = "Last command undone";
                    } else {
                        result = "No command to undo";
                        search = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case "R":
                    if (manager.canRedo()){
                        manager.redo();
                        result = "Last undone commande redone";
                    } else {
                        result = "No command to redo";
                        search = true;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    result = "Could not interpret " + input + " as a command";
                    search = true;
            }
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Format the options available to a user.
     * @param manager BattleManager handling the battle.
     * @return a String presenting all the available options to the user.
     */
    public static String possibleOptions(BattleManager manager){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(
                "Possible options are:\nA: attack the other actor.\nM: move to a new position.");
        if (manager.canUndo()){
            builder.append("\nU: undo the last command.");
        }
        if (manager.canRedo()){
            builder.append("\nR: redo the last command.");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
    /**
     * Handle the acquisition of a coordinate for a {@link Move} action from the user.
     * @param scanner Scanner used to parse the user input.
     * @param coordinate Which of the coordinates to ask from the user.
     * @return 
     */
    public static int getMoveDestination(Scanner scanner, String coordinate){
        System.out.println("Enter the " + coordinate + "-coordinate of your destination");
        if (!scanner.hasNextInt()){
            do{
                System.out.println("Could not parse " + scanner.next() 
                        + " as an integer, please try again");
            } while (!scanner.hasNextInt());
        }
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some of your code formatting is a little bit claustrophobic - you're missing a blank line between several of your functions in `Actor`, for example.

It's good that you've started writing some javadocs, but comments like this:

```
    /** Return the current number of health points of the actor. */
```

are redundant and are less preferable to there being no docstring at all. In other words, `getCurrentHp` has a good name and its function is obvious. As a counter-example, the docstring for `injure` is probably good as-is.

The parens at the `return` of `isAlive` should be removed.

Since `Command` is an interface, `public` is implied and those keywords should be removed from its methods.

`Attack` is a simple, immutable class that should be converted to a `record`.

I don't see the benefit to `Move` keeping the `origin` and `endpoint` coordinates as arrays. Why not store them as separate x/y variables, since that's how they're always used?

`BattleManager.move()` mixes two concerns: performing the move, and describing the move in a string. These should be separated.

Repeated-concatenation like

```
actor.name + " moves from [" + actor.getXPosition() + ", " 
                + actor.getYPosition() + "] to [" + x + ", " + y + "].";
```

should be replaced with a string format call.

`Main` has all-static methods. Consider reworking this class to have `main()` be the only static method; have it instantiate its own `Main` class; store your scanner as a member on the class.

Consider replacing your `handleTurn` switch with new [expression-switch syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html).

Your `Main.possibleOptions` string builder is non-ideal since it hard-codes a system-specific newline. Consider replacing this with a `StringWriter`+`PrintWriter` which has better [format and print methods](https://devdocs.io/openjdk%7E17/java.base/java/io/printwriter).

You have inconsistent use of `this.`. I'm in the "only use it when required" camp, and in this style it would be deleted from many of the places you've used it currently.

Comment: Thank you for the time you took reviewing my code. I cannot take immediately into account the record and expression-switch syntax because I am still using Java11 but thank you for hinting them to me. Apart from the points you mention, would you consider my implementation of undo/redo sane enough, especially considering the number of places where part of each possible action will have to be defined?